# "Kommt ein Mann in eine Kneipe..." - Wieso haben Witze diesen besonderen Satzbau?

Tags: grammar, joke

Wenn jemand einen Satz in der Form

> *"Kommt ein Mann in eine Kneipe..."*

beginnt, kann der Zuhörer ziemlich sicher sein, dass gerade ein [Witz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witz) erzählt wird.

Aber wieso gibt es im Deutschen diese besondere Satzform? Wird sie noch für andere Anlässe verwendet?

---

*Ergänzender Edit:* mir geht es darum, dass durch diese Konstruktion der Zuhörer alleine durch die *Syntax* (die Wortstellung/den Satzbau) bereits ableiten kann, dass es ein Witz ist, und nicht erst durch die *Semantik* (die Inhalte).

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das speziell im Deutschen ist. "A man walks into a bar" ist mindestens genauso populär.

Comment: Das ist wahr. Allerdings könnte "a man walks into a bar" auch der Beginn einer anderen beliebigen Geschichte sein (z.B. einer dramatischen Erzählung) - alleine die Tatsache, dass offenbar viele Witze mit Männern in Kneipen zu tun haben, lassen den Schluß zu, dass es sich hier wohl um den Beginn eines Witzes handelt. Es ist also im Englischen eine Frage der *Semantik*. Im Deutschen fiele mir aber schon von vornherein keine andere Bedeutung eines Satzes ein, der in dieser Form beginnt. Es ist also im Deutschen eine Frage der *Syntax*.

Comment: @musiKk: Es hängt ja auch nur am Satzbau, nicht an den Worten; "Geht ein Briefträger zum Briefkasten" deutete ebenso auf den Beginn eines Witzes hin und das gibt es vermutlich so nicht sehr häufig im Englischen. Der Satzbau in "A man walks into a bar" ist ja auch nicht besonders, sondern "ganz normal", also ist das kein Vergleich.

Comment: Ich finde es zwar dennoch nicht eindeutig, aber ich bin offensichtlich überstimmt.

Comment: @musiKk: Hast du denn vielleicht ein gutes Beispiel, wo dieser Satzbau verwendet wird und es nicht auf einen Witz hinausläuft? Ich hätte es jedenfalls wie Jan auf Anhieb so interpretiert (unabhängig von der Kneipe und dem Mann, der dort hin kommt).

Comment: @musiKk, dann hatte ich Dich zuerst mißverstanden: ich dachte Du meintest, die Eindeutigkeit aufgrund des Satzbaus ist sowohl im Deutschen als auch im Englischen gegeben. Falls das nicht der Fall ist: inwiefern ist der Satzbau im Deutschen denn *nicht* ein eindeutiger Hinweis auf einen Witz?

Comment: "Kommt ein Mann in ein Kneipe und trinkt ein Bier." Ist das witzig? Nein. Siehst Du, damit ist Deine Grundannahme widerlegt. :)

Comment: @JohnSmithers: ...und Du würdest da ernsthaft *keinen Witz* erwarten? Ich behaupte nicht, dass es ein guter Witz werden würde - es gibt auch Witze, die findet niemand außer dem Erzähler witzig. Ich gehe aber davon aus, dass so ein Satz normalerweise nur mit der *Intention des Sprechers, einen Witz zu erzählen*, so formuliert wird.

Comment: Ich denke auch, daß dieser Satzbau in Hauptsätzen fast ausschließlich in Witzen vorkommt; das einzige andere Beispiel, das mir einfällt, ist "Kommt ein Vogel geflogen".

Comment: @Jan: Sagen wir mal so. Ich wüsste auch kein realistisches Beispiel im Englischen, bei dem "a xyz walks into a bar" keinen Witz einleitet. Ich könnte jetzt krampfhaft eines suchen, aber das lasse ich mal. Du hast aber Recht; die Satzstellung im Deutschen ist schon speziell (ist die überhaupt grammatisch richtig?).

Comment: Besseres Beispiel, in dem das Genre Witz nur an der Wortstellung und sonstigen Grobstruktur erkennbar ist: Sitzen zwei Hochhäuser im Keller und stricken Plastiksackerl. Sagt das eine zum andern: Du, es ist bald Weihnachten. Sagt das andere: Macht nichts, ich bin eh mit'm Radl da.

Comment: Sehr interessante Beobachtung! Die Frage wäre klarer, wenn du die Satzform genauer charakterisiert hättest (nicht nur anhand von Beispielen).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Die **Verbspitzenstellung** kann als Stilmittel zur Dramatisierung eingesetzt werden. [Peter Auer (1993)](http://www.freidok.uni-freiburg.de/volltexte/4487/) schrieb in seiner überaus sorgfältigen wissenschaftlichen Abhandlung *"Zur Verbspitzenstellung im gesprochenen Deutsch"* über Witze:

> Die Verbspitzenstellung kommt natürlich auch in schriftlichen Texten vor, die die gesprochene Sprache zu imitieren suchen. Das gilt besonders für die Gattung des Witzes [...]
>
> Dies gilt für Erzählungen, besonders aber für Witze: hier hat die
> einleitende Verbspitzenstellung sogar eine Signalfunktion für die Erkennung der Gattung angenommen.

Daneben finden sich aber in der zitierten Abhandlung reichlich weitere Beispiele für die Verbspitzenstellung, mir fällt spontan folgendes Kinderlied ein:

> Will ich in mein Gärtlein gehn,
> will mein Zwieblein gießen,
> steht ein bucklig Männlein da,
> fängt gleich an zu niesen.

Auch Goethe benutzt dieses Stilmittel im [Heideröslein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heider%C3%B6slein):

> Sah ein Knab' ein Röslein stehn,
> Röslein auf der Heiden,
> war so jung und morgenschön,
> lief er schnell, es nah zu sehn,
> sah's mit vielen Freuden.
> Röslein, Röslein, Röslein rot,
> Röslein auf der Heiden.

Comment: Ich wundere mich immer, mit was für einem Schwachsinn dieser Goethe so bekannt geworden ist. Das Kinderlied ist jedenfalls deutlich gehaltvoller und übrigens auch sprachlich dichter.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ist dir klar, dass in dem Gedicht eine Vergewaltigung beschrieben wird? Nicht, dass ich das besonders begrüßen würde, aber die Sprachkunst in dieser Allegorie ist schon ziemlich fortgeschritten.

Answer (score 2):

Gegenbeispiele:

- "Kommt ein Gewitter?" - in Frageform kommt dieser Satzbau auch vor; was ist aber genau der Satzbau, was gehört zur typischen Form? Beginnt mit Verb/Infinitiv, dann Subjekt... ("Kommt eine Blondine ...", "Geht ein Häschen ...", "Liegt ein Kardinal...", ...)
- "Steht der Minutenzeiger horizontal, ist es viertel vor oder viertel nach." Hei, ich hab' eins gefunden, das keine Frage ist, wodurch sich also auch die Stimme nicht am Satzende hebt.
- "Ist der Ruf erst ruiniert, regiert sich's gänzlich ungeniert" - ein Sprichwort.

#### Zusammengefasst:

- Wird sie noch für andere Anlässe verwendet?

### Ja

Wieso wird diese Satzform verwendet?

Ich schwimme hier, aber wage einen Versuch. Das Verb reißt einen in die Handlung, die Aktion, die Situation förmlich hinein. Es gibt keine langatmige Einleitung "Seht da ist die Witwe Bolte", die erst mühsam die Personen einführt, sondern wie ein Splashpanel im Comic geht es gleich mit einer Situation los, die neugierig macht - ähnlich wie im Tatort i.d.R. die erste Leiche in den ersten 5 Minuten auftaucht/der erste Mord passiert.

Und dann läßt der Satz erstmal alles offen - "Kommt ein Häschen i.d. Apotheke." Ja schön. Wenn es doch einer Einleitung bedarf kommt sie jetzt: "Der Apotheker, schon etwas schwerhörig, fragt das Kaninchen: 'Hafft Du Nuffty?'".

Alternativ hätte die Geschichte beginnen können: "Ein älterer Apotheker, schon etwas schwerhörig, steht in seiner Apotheke". Das ist bedächtiger, und märchenartiger. "Bescheiden setzt er die Preise herab" - ja, klar - ein Märchen!

Sagt das Nilpferd: "Wir sind die drei heiligen Könige, und wollen unsere Geschenke zurück" - sagt der Hase: "Der Witz funktioniert so nicht! Drittens bin ich kein Kaninchen." Darauf die Frau des Apothekers: "Sind wir schon Max-Weber-Platz?"

Comment: In den "Gegenbeispielen" steht dieser Satzbau in Frage- und Nebensätzen. Das besondere an der Witzform ist, daß er für Hauptsätze verwendet wird. Das einzige, was mir einfällt, wo es das sonst noch gibt, ist "Kommt ein Vogel geflogen" -- komischerweise auch mit "kommt" wie bei vielen Witzen, aber das wird vielleicht Zufall sein.

Answer (score 1):

> Treffen sich zwei Blondinen ...
>
> Ein Priester, ein Rabbi und ein Imam treffen sich im Bordell und fanden das Paradies.

Ja, man erwartet einen Witz bei einer gewissen Satzkonstruktion, aber das liegt daran, daß schon tausende solcher Witze in dieser Art und Weise erzählt wurden.

Blondinenwitze hatten ihre "Hype-Periode", sobald jemand einen Satz mit Blondinen anfing, erwartete man einen Witz, das ist halt auch heute noch so. Wenn das alle fünf Minuten passiert, gewöhnt man sich dran, daß dann ein Witz folgt. Gleiches gilt für die Kneipe und den Mann.

Ansonsten ist die ungewöhnliche Kombination der Witz-Protagonisten und des Szenarios (und natürlich der Tonfall des Sprechers) ein Indikator für einen zu erwarteten Witz. Bei "Ein Hund, ein Lama und ein Kamel treffen sich im Schönheitssalon" ist schon aus der *aberwitzigen* Situation ein Witz vorhersehbar.

Comment: Stimmt alles, geht aber meines Erachtens an der Frage vorbei... Kannst Du mir denn eine *andere Verwendung* dieser besonderen Satzkonstruktion nennen?

Comment: @Jan: Das hatte ich bereits oben als Kommentar zu Deiner Frage getan. Bei normalen alltäglichen Erzählungen/Diskussionen. "Stell dir vor da kommt ein Mann in die Kneipe und bestellt fünf Bier auf einmal. Alle für sich. Das fünfte war schal bevor er am dritten war." Nur würde heute keiner mehr mit dem typischen "Ein Mann kommt..." anfangen, weil es sich eben als Witzanfang etabliert hat. Du kannst auch über Blondinen reden ohne einen Witz zu implizieren. Nur wird halt dieser spezielle Anfang bewußt weggelassen, weil er als Witz etabliert ist.

Comment: So gesehen ist das ganz klassische Konditionierung.

Comment: Die in der Frage beschriebene Satzkonstruktion wird im zweiten hier genannten Beispiel ("Ein Priester, ein Rabbi ...") überhaupt nicht verwendet. Dazu müsste der Satz schon heißen: "Treffen sich ein Priester, ein Rabbi und ein Imam ...".

Answer (score 1):

Das ist eine normale Konstruktion wenn man etwas erzählt, z.B. könnte man sagen "Kommt gestern ein Mann in die Kneipe, ...".  Das besondere am Witz ist wohl, daß er abstrakt bleibt, und keine konkreten Angabe über Ort, Zeit, Personen, ... macht.

Comment: "Sagt Genosse Palinkowski auf dem 27 Parteitag des Zentralrats der KPdSU ...". "Sitzen Hitler, Roosevelt, Stalin und Churchill gemeinsam im Flugzeug". Witze können in jeder Hinsicht konkret sein, und müssen das teilweise sein, insbes. politische Witze.

Comment: Vielleicht kann man auch sagen, dass die Witze keinen direkten Bezug zum Sprecher haben, d.h. der Sprecher kann das nicht selbst erlebt haben. Man könnte natürlich auch den Witz erst mal als Geschichte tarnen, und die Zuhörer etwas an der Nase herumführen.

Comment: Sagen kann man viel, ja. "Pass uff! Neulich, ich so zu meiner Freundin, kennste? Kennste, kennste, kennste?" Ich stimme zu, dass die meisten Witze vom Erzähler nicht mit sich in Bezug gebracht werden, andere Witzereißer dagegen erzählen alle Witze so, als seien sie ihnen selbst widerfahren.