# "gesagt habe ich Ihnen, dass.." als Stirnsatz?

Tags: sentence-structure

Ist es richtig, wenn ich einen Satz mit *gesagt habe* beginne? z.B.

> Gesagt habe ich Ihnen gestern, dass..

Ich erinnere mich an so etwas in dem Roman *Der Prozess* von Kafka.

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/kommt-ein-mann-in-eine-kneipe-wieso-haben-witze-diesen-besonderen-satzbau

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deutsch hat den Vorteil, dass die grammatischen Funktionen von Worten und Wortgruppen meist leicht anhand der Beugungen und Deklination erkannt werden können. Aus diesem Grund bestehen für die Anordnung der Bestandteile eines Satzes mehr Freiheiten als in vielen anderen Sprachen.

Daher sind all diese Varianten korrekte Anfänge von deutschen Sätzen:

> Ich habe Ihnen gestern gesagt, dass ...
>   Ihnen habe ich gestern gesagt, dass ...
>   Gestern habe ich Ihnen gesagt, dass ...

Auch die folgende Variante ist zulässig, wenn auch unüblich:

> Gesagt habe ich Ihnen gestern, dass ...

Die Akzeptanz dieser Version steigt beträchtlich, wenn das erste Wort (»Gesagt«) stark betont wird, und in Opposition zu etwas anderem gestellt wird:

> **Gesagt** habe ich Ihnen gestern, dass wir für Ihren Auftrag leider keine Kapazitäten mehr haben. **Verstanden** haben sie vermutlich aber, dass wir Ihren Auftrag gar nicht durchführen wollen. Das ist ein Missverständnis.

Answer (score 1):

*Gesagt* nach vorne zu holen hebt dies hervor, was vielleicht zu Unterscheidungszwecken nützlich sein kann - schließlich könnte etwas anderes *geschrieben* worden sein.

*Sie haben mir doch gestern gesagt, XXX* - *XXX habe ich **geschrieben**. Gesagt habe ich Ihnen gestern, YYY*

Sofern jedoch die Übermittlungsmethode eigentlich nicht im Fokus steht, klingt diese Satzstellung sehr seltsam.