# Wortreihenfolge: "Rede ich ungern drüber."

Tags: word-order

[In diesem Video um 0:48](https://youtu.be/jC-ZZZE4dX0?t=47) sagt eine Deutsche, die auf der Straße interviewt wird und gerade gefragt wurde, "Was verdienst du?", "Rede ich ungern drüber." Warum hat sie ihre Antwort so formuliert, statt "Ich rede ungern drüber"? Manchmal begegne ich solchen Sätzen, die mit dem Verb anfangen, und manchmal erklären sie sich dadurch, dass das erste Wort einfach fehlt (z. B. "Weiß ich nicht" statt "Das weiß ich nicht"), aber ich glaube, diese Erklärung gilt für diesen Satz nicht (oder wenn doch, fällt mir das fehlende Wort nicht ein).

Ich habe [diesen Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/kommt-ein-mann-in-eine-kneipe-wieso-haben-witze-diesen-besonderen-satzbau) gelesen, in dem der besondere Gebrauch der sogenannten Verbspitzenstellung beschrieben wird, wenn es um einen Witz geht, was im Video nicht der Fall ist (und in welchem Fall man vielleicht behaupten könnte, dass ein vorn stehendes "Es" dem Satz sowieso fehlt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zum einen werden in der Umgangssprache die [Präpositionaladverbien](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/207) gerne getrennt oder *da* gedoppelt und getrennt.

> Davon weiß ich nichts.
> Da weiß ich nichts von.
> Da weiß ich nichts davon.

> Darüber haben wir nicht gesprochen.
> Da haben wir nicht d(a)rüber gesprochen.

Zum anderen wird bei Antworten auf Fragen gerne von der [Vorfeld-Analepse](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1999) Gebrauch gemacht. Die Frage führt ein Thema ein, das in der Antwort nicht wiederholt wird; so entstehen scheinbare Verberstsätze.

> Was kostet der Spaß? – Weiß ich nicht.
> Wann kommt das Paket? – Ist seit gestern unterwegs.

Das Interessante ist, dass das getrennnte *da* der Präpositionaladverbien ein solches Thema vertreten kann, *darüber* dagegen nicht.

> Was verdienst du? – Rede ich ungern drüber.
> Was verdienst du? – *Rede ich ungern.

Das nicht verbalisierte Element muss im Vorfeld stehen.

> Wann kommt das Paket? – *Seit gestern ist unterwegs.

Answer (score 0):

Doch, dein Ansatz ist schon richtig. Auch hier "fehlt" das erste Wort, "Da"

> Da rede ich ungern drüber.

Comment: Ach so, danke. Aber was an Bedeutung verleiht "da" dem Satz, die im Wort "drüber" nicht schon eingeschlossen ist?